# How to convert xml string-array of comma-separated values into a 2D ArrayList

Tags: java, android, xml, string, arraylist

For a simple Android app, I have data in my strings.xml file of the following format:

```
<string-array>
   <item>a,true,true,false</item>
   <item>b,true,false,false</item>
   <item>c,false,false,false</item>
</string-array>
```

I would like to read this into a 2D ArrayList so that I can do a variety of filtering operations of the list based on the boolean values.

So far I have tried something like this but the last line, of course, is an error, because the types are not appropriate:

```
csvList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.csv_list));
for (int i = 0; i < csvList.size(); i++) {
    String singleRow = csvList.get(i);
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList(singleRow.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    completeList.add(Arrays.asList(items));
}
```

Comment: So I think I answered my own question! All I did was replace the last line with completeList.add(items) and that seemed to work. Easier than I thought.

Comment: You need to show the completeList declaration to properly answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the last line of the loop from:

```
completeList.add(Arrays.asList(items));
```

to

```
completeList.add(items);
```